# Creating pyramid like array from numeric array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

My question is the following:

I'm looking tor an algorithm which makes `$array1` look like `$pyramid`.

I Have this array:

```
$array1 = [
    'foo',
    'baz',
    'bar',
    'apple'
];
```

And I want to create a new array (`$pyramid`) from `$array1` which looks like this:

```
$pyramid = [
    'foo' => [
        'baz' => [
            'bar' => [
                'apple' => ' '
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

The example `$array1` has 4 elements, but it can be arbitrarily long, so the algorithm should work any dimension.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Why do you want so?

Comment: Huh, that's hard to explain. I want to use it for Config settings on my website. I've created an array (lets call now pattern) which contains evry details of an input field like: name, value, type, min/max rules placeholder and so on. But, evry of this fields are empty in this pattern. I have an another array with settings, but i defined the settings like this: display/name/something, rules/min/50 etc. So i exploded theese strings by / , and it generated an array like: $exploded['display','name','something'] so i want to build the pyramid from that, to fond the match with the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
$pyramid = [];
$pyramidPtr = &$pyramid;

foreach ($array1 as $element) {
    $pyramidPtr[$element] = null;
    $pyramidPtr = &$pyramidPtr[$element];
}
unset($pyramidPtr);

var_dump($pyramid);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk` along with `array_reverse` like as

```
$reversed = array_reverse($array1);
$result = [];
array_walk($reversed,function($v,$k)use(&$result){
   $result = $v ? [$v => $result] : "";
});

print_r($result);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/453783)